# android studio build failed because of "Cannot cast object '11' with class 'java.lang.Integer' to class "

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Android studio version is 0.5.2, and the gradle version is 1.11, I update android studio to 0.6.0 this morning but build failed, so I removed it and reinstall 0.5.2, but it still build failed.

The line 15 of gradle-library.gradle is minSdkVersion=11, I don't know what's wrong with my ide, I update gradle to 1.12, but failed again.

> D:\Develop\android_alex\SRC>gradle clean Parallel execution is an
>   incubating feature.   Error listing versions of
>   com.android.tools.build:gradle using class
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenVersionLister$1.
>   Will attempt an alternate way to list versions. This behaviour has
>   been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
>
> > FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:                     Script 'D:\Develop\android_alex\SRC\config\android-library.gradle' line: 15
> - What went wrong:           A problem occurred evaluating script.
>
>   > Cannot cast object '11' with class 'java.lang.Integer' to class 'com.android.builder.model.ApiVersion'
> - Try:                       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 1):

Your minSDkVersion should not have a `=` in it.

Your Gradle build file should look something like this:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
    }
}
```